# Shutdown my computer automatically after copying files

Tags: windows-7

Well, I have Windows 7 and I want to make my computer shutdown after copying some files into a USB memory. Is there a way to do it without installing any program?

I've read about a program called Teracopy, but I would like to avoid using programs like this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i would suggest simply creating and running a batch file.

Say you want to copy C:\mydir\my_super_huge_file.dat to F:\thumbdrivedir\

Using notepad or cmd console, create a file called copy_file_and_shutdown.bat with the following 2 commands:

**copy c:\mydir\my_super_huge_file.dat f:\thumbdrivedir**

**shutdown /s**

Simply Run the file (ie. from DOS prompt, run the command *copy_file_and_shutdown*)

It will perform the commmands in sequence, copying the file first. Once copying is finished, the second command will shutdown the computer.

:)